# bootstrap button loading with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to delete a record for mysql using ajax. everything is working fine. but i also want to add loading to the button when i click on trash button. below is my button link

```
<a href="#" id="delpost" data-id="'.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-default pull-right" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
```

and below is my ajax

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '#delpost', function() {
        var del_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var info = 'id=' + del_id;
        var parent = $(this).closest('li');
        var btn = $(this);
        btn.button('loading');
        if (confirm("Sure you want to delete this Post? There is NO undo!")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/delete-post.php",
                data: info,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    parent.animate({
                        'backgroundColor': '#fb6c6c'
                    }, 300);
                },
                success: function() {
                    btn.button('reset');
                    parent.slideUp(300, function() {
                        parent.remove();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, Where is the question?

Comment: you can use something like [this](http://msurguy.github.io/ladda-bootstrap/)

Answer (score 0):

> This is simple jQuery solution and has nothing to do with bootstrap

You can add a hidden image of loading.gif which you can download from google and adjust its css so that it appears in same line as your delete link :

```
<a href="#" id="delpost" data-id="'.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-default pull-right" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a> <img src="path/to/your/loading.gif" style="display:none;" alt="loading" id="loading" />
```

And modify your jquery code as below :

```
$(function() {
        $('body').on('click','#delpost',function(){
            var del_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
            var info = 'id=' + del_id;
            var parent = $(this).closest('li');
            var btn=$(this);
            btn.button('loading');
            if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this Post? There is NO undo!"))
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/delete-post.php",
                    data: info,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
                        $('#loading').show();//shows loading gif image
                    },
                    success: function(){
                        $('#loading').hide();//hides loading gif image
                        btn.button('reset');
                        parent.slideUp(300,function() {
                            parent.remove();
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: @AseshaGeorge are you getting any error in your firebug console?

Comment: @AseshaGeorge, you can open your console in firebug in firefox browser and type 
jQuery('#loading');
See if it returns an object and on hover of this object it should highlight your loading.gif image which is hidden so you need to show it :
jQuery('#loading').show();

Comment: content is loaded form another page image link is on another page and ajax is on index page. dose it be a problem?

Comment: you need to add the image tag as I have posted after your link (anchor tag), also modify your ajax script to show this image in beforesend and hide it on success of ajax